# onHover on image using javascript, how to get text to the left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So my goal is to have an image pop up on the hover on top of another image, with some text. I get the image to popup etc, but the text is always appearing on top and I don't know how to style just the text to the right. Here's my code:

```js
/*

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Code for link-hover text boxes
By Nicolas Höning
Usage: <a onmouseover="nhpup.popup('popup text' [, {'class': 'myclass', 'width': 300}])">a link</a>
The configuration dict with CSS class and width is optional - default is class .pup and width of 200px.
You can style the popup box via CSS, targeting its ID #pup. 
You can escape " in the popup text with &quot;.
Tutorial and support at http://nicolashoening.de?twocents&nr=8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

The MIT License (MIT)

Copyright (c) 2014 Nicolas Höning

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.
*/

nhpup = {

    pup: null,      // This is the popup box, represented by a div    
    identifier: "pup",  // Name of ID and class of the popup box
    minMargin: 15,  // Set how much minimal space there should be (in pixels)
                    // between the popup and everything else (borders, mouse)
    default_width: 200, // Will be set to width from css in document.ready
    move: false,   // Move it around with the mouse? we are only ready for that when the mouse event is set up.
                   // Besides, having this turned off initially is resource-friendly.

    /*
     Write message, show popup w/ custom width if necessary,
      make sure it disappears on mouseout
    */
    popup: function(p_msg, p_config)
    {
        // do track mouse moves and update position 
        this.move = true;
        // restore defaults
        this.pup.removeClass()
                .addClass(this.identifier)
                .width(this.default_width);

        // custom configuration
        if (typeof p_config != 'undefined') {
            if ('class' in p_config) {
                this.pup.addClass(p_config['class']);
            }
            if ('width' in p_config) {
                this.pup.width(p_config['width']);
            }
        }

        // Write content and display
        this.pup.html(p_msg).show();

        // Make sure popup goes away on mouse out and we stop the constant 
        //  positioning on mouse moves.
        // The event obj needs to be gotten from the virtual 
        //  caller, since we use onmouseover='nhpup.popup(p_msg)' 
        var t = this.getTarget(arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0]);
        $jq(t).unbind('mouseout').bind('mouseout', 
            function(e){
                nhpup.pup.hide();
                nhpup.move = false;
            }
        );
    },

    // set the target element position
    setElementPos: function(x, y)
    {
        // Call nudge to avoid edge overflow. Important tweak: x+10, because if
        //  the popup is where the mouse is, the hoverOver/hoverOut events flicker
        var x_y = this.nudge(x + 10, y);
        // remember: the popup is still hidden
        this.pup.css('top', x_y[1] + 'px')
                .css('left', x_y[0] + 'px');
    },

    /* Avoid edge overflow */
    nudge: function(x,y)
    {
        var win = $jq(window);

        // When the mouse is too far on the right, put window to the left
        var xtreme = $jq(document).scrollLeft() + win.width() - this.pup.width() - this.minMargin;
        if(x > xtreme) {
            x -= this.pup.width() + 2 * this.minMargin;
        }
        x = this.max(x, 0);

        // When the mouse is too far down, move window up
        if((y + this.pup.height()) > (win.height() +  $jq(document).scrollTop())) {
            y -= this.pup.height() + this.minMargin;
        }

        return [ x, y ];
    },

    /* custom max */
    max: function(a,b)
    {
        if (a>b) return a;
        else return b;
    },

    /*
     Get the target (element) of an event.
     Inspired by quirksmode
    */
    getTarget: function(e)
    {
        var targ;
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.target) targ = e.target;
        else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
        if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
            targ = targ.parentNode;
        return targ;
    },

    onTouchDevice: function() 
    {
        var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        return deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad|android|blackberry|iemobile|opera m(ob|in)i|vodafone)/) !== null;
    },
 
    initialized: false,
    initialize : function(){
        if (this.initialized) return;

        window.$jq = jQuery; // this is safe in WP installations with noConflict mode (which is default)

        /* Prepare popup and define the mouseover callback */
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            // create default popup on the page
            $jq('body').append('<div id="' + nhpup.identifier + '" class="' + nhpup.identifier + '" style="position:absolute; display:none; z-index:200;"></div>');
            nhpup.pup = $jq('#' + nhpup.identifier);

            // set dynamic coords when the mouse moves
            $jq(document).mousemove(function (e) {
                if (!nhpup.onTouchDevice()) { // turn off constant repositioning for touch devices (no use for this anyway)
                    if (nhpup.move) {
                        nhpup.setElementPos(e.pageX, e.pageY);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        this.initialized = true;
    }
};

if ('jQuery' in window) nhpup.initialize();

/* CSS MENU */
(function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
      
      var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        breakpoint: 768,
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
        if (settings.format != 'select') {
          cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
          $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
            var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
            if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
              mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
            }
            else {
              mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
              if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                mainmenu.find('ul').show();
              }
            }
          });

          multiTg = function() {
            cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
            cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
              if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
              }
              else {
                $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
              }
            });
          };

          if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
          else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
        }

        else if (settings.format === 'select')
        {
          cssmenu.append('<select style="width: 100%"/>').addClass('select-list');
          var selectList = cssmenu.find('select');
          selectList.append('<option>' + settings.title + '</option>', {
                                                         "selected": "selected",
                                                         "value": ""});
          cssmenu.find('a').each(function() {
            var element = $(this), indentation = "";
            for (i = 1; i < element.parents('ul').length; i++)
            {
              indentation += '-';
            }
            selectList.append('<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' + indentation + element.text() + '</option');
          });
          selectList.on('change', function() {
            window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
          });
        }

        if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

        resizeFix = function() {
          if ($(window).width() > settings.breakpoint) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').show();
            cssmenu.removeClass('small-screen');
            if (settings.format === 'select') {
              cssmenu.find('select').hide();
            }
            else {
              cssmenu.find("#menu-button").removeClass("menu-opened");
            }
          }

          if ($(window).width() <= settings.breakpoint && !cssmenu.hasClass("small-screen")) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
            cssmenu.addClass('small-screen');
            if (settings.format === 'select') {
              cssmenu.find('select').show();
            }
          }
        };
        resizeFix();
        return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

      });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    format: "dropdown"
  });

  $("#cssmenu a").each(function() {
   var linkTitle = $(this).text();
   $(this).attr('data-title', linkTitle);
  });
});

});
})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* hover stuff */
/*  hover over popup style */
.pup, .pup_class2, .pup_class3 {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:200; /* aaaalways on top*/
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3db2e1;
  font-size: 0.95em;
}

.pup_class2 {
  background-color: red !important;
}
.pup_class3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

p#tests {
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}

/* end hover stuff /*



/* css menu */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
 #cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: #3db2e1;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #3db2e1;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #dff2fa;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -ms-transform: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  color: #dff2fa;
  background: #19799f;
  content: attr(data-title);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(- -18px);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a::before,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover::before {
  background: #3db2e1;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a::before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #3db2e1;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 17px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 22px;
  height: 3px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  border-top: 2px solid #dff2fa;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dff2fa;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  background: #dff2fa;
}

/* end css menu */

/* test case for the hover over popup */
.testpup{
  width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#rather_wide {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#rather_tall {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html class="" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test nhpup.js</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/nhpup_1.1.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .title {
      font-family: Raleway;
      color: #FF0000;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .subtitle {
      font-family: Raleway;
      color: #0E0E0E;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .interactiveheight {
      height: 180;
      width: 720;
    }
    body {
      background-color: 0081ED;
    }
    .info {
      color: #0E0E0E;
      font-family: Raleway;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>

      <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>History</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='../../DroneAnatomy/index.html'>Drone Anatomy</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Proposed Air Standards</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  A bunch of text is here, Didn't think relevant to put in.
  <div align="left">

    <a onmouseover="nhpup.popup('TEXT HERE: &lt;br&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt; &lt;img src=&quot;HighSpeedSlice.jpg&quot;&gt;', {'width': 90});">
      <img height="180" width="720" src="FlightBufferFromAircraft.jpg" />
    </a>
    <br />

    <a onmouseover="nhpup.popup('In the high speed range, the 600ft will be split up into 8 zones. Four of those eight zones will be flight zones, and the remaining four will be buffer zones to allow for direction change. As the picture shows, there are four 50 foot buffers for transferring directions and four 100 ft. zones for travel headed North, South, East, and West.&lt;br&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt; &lt;img src=&quot;DirectionsHighSpeed.jpg&quot;&gt;', {'width': 90});">
      <img height="180" width="720" src="HighSpeedSlice.jpg" onMouseOver="" />
    </a>
    <br />

    <a onmouseover="nhpup.popup('Computer controlled buoys...: &lt;br&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt; &lt;img src=&quot;LowSpeedDirections.jpg&quot;&gt;', {'width': 90});">
      <img height="180" width="720" src="LowSpeedSlice.jpg" onMouseOver="" />
    </a>
    <br />

    <a onmouseover="nhpup.popup('TEXT HERE: &lt;br&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt; &lt;img src=&quot;GroundBufferDirections.jpg&quot;&gt;', {'width': 90});">
      <img height="180" width="720" src="Flightbufferground.jpg" onMouseOver="" />
    </a>
    <br />
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you set an image as a background for the popup. This does not work in all the cases (e.g. with responsive design), but is much more simpler than playing around with overlays...

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how would that help the effort to get the text to the right?

Comment: @SignalR Sorry, I misunderstood your issue. Have you tried to add text-align: right; to .pup, .pup_class2, .pup_class3 classes?

Comment: @RomanHutnyk yes, it had no effect on the text.

Comment: @SignalR there is nhpup.popup plugin, that creates popup for you. Can you post HTML snippet of that popup? - Can't catch it here.

Comment: @RomanHutnyk It's in the top block of code under the MIT lisence